# revolute and prismatic joint in one

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello, can i make prismatic and revolute joint in one point( control only for prismatic)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23294/revolute-and-prismatic-joint-in-one/) by [Pakras](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14001/pakras/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can try to model this combination as a revolute joint and a prismatic joint in series with a zero-length link between them.

For example, you would connect your base to the zero-length link using the prismatic joint and then the child link to the zero-length link using the revolute joint.

---

Originally posted by [bhej](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5475/bhej/) with karma: 93 on 2019-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pakras](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14001/pakras/) on 2019-07-24**:
Thank you very much, it works!

**Comment by [dkoung](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16763/dkoung/) on 2019-09-26**:
hello,
so what's about the *visual* and *collision*, they are in which link or both of them?